# "sehr ernsthaft" vs "sehr ernst"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verb

Why is there a difference between `sehr ernsthaft` vs `sehr ernst`?
In English it both means `very seriously`.

**When do I use which?**

E.g. from the same document:

1. Und wir halten solches Streben für sehr ernst.
2. Diese Zusammenkünfte sollten meiner Ansicht nach sehr ernsthaft genommen werden

Comment: Die Frage hat doch mit dem `sehr` nichts zu tun, das kann man doch überall rauskürzen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While both *also* mean *serious*, *ernsthaft* has some other meanings than *ernst*, and they are mostly not interchangeable.

Example for when you can *not* use *ernst*:

> Willst Du mir ernsthaft erzählen, dass ... (are you *really* trying to tell me ...)

Example for when you can *not* use *ernsthaft*:

> Meinst Du das ernst? (Are you serious?)

Generally, you should be able to replace *ernstaft* by *im Ernst*, while you can for the most part not exchange *ernst* with *im Ernst* (with one exception maybe being *Meinst Du das ernst/im Ernst?*, where the *im Ernst* variant is in my experience used rarely, mostly in spoken German).

---

[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ernsthaft) tells us:

> ernst: not in a light mood, threatening
>   ernsthaft: haunting, grave, sincere

Comment: Meinst du ernsthaft, dass man ernsthaft nicht verwenden kann, wenn man jemanden ernsthaft fragen will, ob er etwas ernsthaft so meint, wie er es ernsthaft gesagt hat? Ernsthaft? Da stimme ich dir ernsthaft nicht zu.

Comment: Dang it... I've been writing on my answer the last 2 hours (traveling through town), just to find your good answer here that you'Ve written in the meantime. +1 from me

Comment: Ich glaube ernstlich, dass es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung gibt, ob jemand etwas ernst sagt oder ernsthaft. Etwas ernst sagen heißt, etwas in nicht lustiger Weise zu äußern. Etwas ernsthaft zu sagen, heißt, es mit Wohlbedacht zu sagen (Gegenfrage wäre "Nein! Das hat er doch nicht ernsthaft [im Sinne von *tatsächlich*] gesagt?"

Comment: Example for the above comment in German: I can say *ernst* that I hate dogs (i.e. in a serious tone). I can not, however, say it *ernsthaft*, because it is a plain lie.

Answer (score 5):

As you already pointed out `ernst` can be translated as *serious(ly)* and in this sense also as *severe, truly, heavily* or *dangerous* etc. depending on the context.

If you split `ernsthaft` into its two parts ernst-haft, you would translate it as `ernst`-like or in a `ernst` manner.

So, `ernster Professor` would most likely be a stern person, while `ernsthafter Student` would be (most of the times) a diligent person.

Answering your question:
`Diese Zusammenkünfte sollten meiner Ansicht nach sehr ernsthaft genommen werden` is at least uncommon, if not wrong. It rather would be `ernst genommen werden` or `ernsthaft wahrgenommen werden`. The first one meaning the gatherings should be taken seriously (not lightly), the later one that the meetings should be used earnestly.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO:  `sehr ernsthaft` makes no sense

BUT

`ernsthaft` is used to enforce something.

`seriously you have to do this!` => `ernsthaft, du musst das machen!`

`i promise! seriously!` => `versprochen! ernsthaft!`

e.g.

`das ist ernsthaft` => no valid german sentence!

you have to say this

`das ist ernst` => `this is serious`

Comment: ... but `das ist ernsthaft schwer` (this is realy heavy) again would be a valid sentence, as well as `ich bin ernsthaft` (i am an earnest person).

Comment: i would say `das ist schwer, ernsthaft` oder `das ist echt/wirklich/sehr/außerordentlich/unerwartet schwer` but `ich bin ernsthaft davon überzeugt..` is valid i agree